# Does PHP not allow typecasting an array as object during initialisation of a variable?

Tags: php, arrays, object, casting

I'm using this code to initialize a multi-dimensional array:

```
protected $availableAuthMechanisms = [
    'open' => (object)[
        'owner'       => 'Mohsin.Auth',
        'name'        => 'Open',
        'identifier'  => 'open'
    ]
];
```

And I get an error that says "**Constant expression contains invalid operations**". What is going on here?--how do I achieve this properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot cast an array inside an array to an object when defining it.

What you could do is cast the array to an object once you retrieve it.

Example:

```
protected $availableAuthMechanisms = [
    'open' => [
        'owner'       => 'Mohsin.Auth',
        'name'        => 'Open',
        'identifier'  => 'open'
    ]
];

$obj = (object) $this->availableAuthMechanisms['open'];
```

Comment: That's a shame. I thought I was messing something up as I saw an example in php.net where this was being used the way I did it in my question. >> https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#117149

Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: @SaifurRahmanMohsin Ah yes, in that example the array is also casted to an object right after assigning it to a variable ;)